# When focusing clone the last input and append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a new input when clicking to the last input. Whenever I focus the last input I want to creat another one and append to it under the previous one. And I want to increase the name attr 1 by 1.

Here's the html,

```
<div id="ingredientsCtr" class="hidden">
   <label class="label">Malzemeleri yazın</label>
   <input name="ingredient1" type="text" class="req-string req-min default-input" rel="ingredientsCtr"/>
</div>
```

This is the jscript code

```
$("#ingredientsCtr").find("input:last").on("focus", function(){
               $(this).clone(true).appendTo("#ingredientsCtr");

           });
```

It clones everyinput when I focus on I just want to duplicate the last one.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#ingredientsCtr").find("input:last").on("focus", function(){
               $(this).clone().appendTo("#ingredientsCtr");

           });
```